# Choosing a location for installation of Docker Desktop app’s CLI tools

Tags: command-line, docker, system-installation, macos

When completing the installation of Docker Desktop 4.25, the *Advanced Settings* offers a choice:

> Choose how to configure the installation of Docker's CLI tools:
>
> **System (requires password)** 
> Docker CLI tools are installed under /usr/local/bin.
>
> **User**
> Docker CLI tools are installed under $HOME/.docker/bin. Note: You need to manually add $HOME/.docker/bin to your PATH. Learn more⁠

Being new to Linux & Docker, I would like to know the trade-offs between these two options.

I am guessing from the "System" name that the first option would make the CLI tools available to all users on this host OS. In contrast, I assume the second option would make the CLI tools available on to my particular user, not other users on the host OS. The user-specific install is already privileged, so no superuser password needed, while the all-users option does require a superuser password. Is this correct?

Are there any other ramifications to choosing one option over the other?

I did read [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/permission-requirements/?uuid=62b61d53-6f5d-471a-9cd5-9364721c073d%0A#installing-symlinks). But that doc offers little guidance, with no pros and cons.

---

I am using macOS Sonoma 14.1 on a MacBook Pro, M1 Pro chip.

Comment: In addition to the installation, updates will also require superuser password if you pick the System installation.

Answer (score 1):

- *Yes, you are right about that*. In system-wide installs, all users can access Docker CLI. However, if they do not have `sudo` or root access, they would not be able to install system-wide binaries.
- Key note: A system-wide install might have permission issues, especially in shared environments, whereas user-specific installs avoid these issues.

If you want user-level control, you can consider using user-specific install.